# On Ubuntu, Python not showing output

Tags: 22.04, python, ruby

I am using Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS and Python 3.10.12. When I write a simple script i.e.`print('hello')` or using ruby with `puts "Hello World"` and run it in a terminal I get no output. This question was originally asked on Stack overflow but was closed. so maybe that means that I should ask the question here. Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: You should include the information from the discussion in your [closed SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77840889/on-ubuntu-python-not-showing-output) so we don't end up asking all the same questions here. Please also include the output of `type -a python3`

Comment: Try running the script while also redirecting STDERR to STDOUT. Maybe there's a silent failure happening and that's why you're not seeing it? `python3 a.py 2>&1`

Comment: I am concerned that you said at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77840889/on-ubuntu-python-not-showing-output#comment137275985_77840889 that you "downloaded deb packages". Python is installed by default on Ubuntu, and you should not install another version

Comment: Please add to your question the literal transcript of a terminal session in which you execute the following four commands (assuming your script is `a.py`): `echo "Hello"`, `cat a.py`, `python3 a.py`, `python3 -c 'print("Hello")'`. Please copy everything, commands and output, to your question.

Comment: Thanks everyone for comments. steeldriver, since you kindly linked to my closed SO question, I assume its not necessary anymore to include the info from there. But yes you'r right I should have. The output you asked for is `python3 is /usr/bin/python3
python3 is /bin/python3`

Comment: Aaron, I havn't yet learned how to do that but I will look into it.

Comment: Daniel T, Actually, I did download 3.12 and installed it but then discovered that was a no no but then rolled it back to the original default.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the CLI, (command line interface), that is, the text terminal in Ubuntu Linux, be sure you are actually running Python interpreter within your CLI.

From the command prompt $, type "python" or perhaps "python3". That should get you a python prompt that looks like this: >>>. That will be where you enter your commands into the python interpreter.

From the python prompt >>> you can type your simple commands.

If you are saving these to a program/script as a .py file, then to run the script you would need to type "python ./hello.py", in order to recruit the python interpreter to run the script.

If you are using a specific development environment (IDE), like VS Code, Eclipe, or PyCharm, or some other, let us know. These are special programs for writing code where you type and save your file in a window within the program. These have their own processes for running the program from the IDE. Most will have a play button somewhere to run the script and give output in a separate pane, e.g., near the bottom of the window as in VS Code.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone and apologies the answer was simple. I had not yet switched on autosave in vscode it now works perfectly.